# CSS How to put an image between buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage, where I want to have the following combination of element:

```
<div><Label>                              <Button1><Image><Button2></div>
```

The problem I discovered is that the whole div is not in one line.

I use this CSS code for the div:

```
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

for the image:

```
clear: both;
width: 90px;
height: 40px;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;
margin-top: 5px;
```

for the button:

```
  float: right;
   margin-top: 12px;
   height: 45px;
   width: 45px;
   margin-right: 5px;
```

This produces the following:

```
 <div><Label><Image>                            <Button1><Button2></div>
```

If I use `float: right` at the image, I will get the following:

```
<div><Label>                           <Button2></div>
                                 <Button1><Image>
```

How can I get the desired behavoiur?

Comment: Please provide meaningful HTML& CSS, ideally in a demo.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, thats because demos DO help with stuff like this.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Since you don't see **every** comment I write you cannot have a basis for that statement. If I think a demo will help, especially such a this one with no meaningful code I feel it's acceptable to ask. especially when there may be other factors of which we are unaware.

Comment: I'm with @Paulie_D here. I can't imagine a single question where a demo (if possible at all) wouldn't help solve the problem at hand faster. Also OP's question and the provided sample code is a little mess and a demo would help a ton. I'm not even motivated to copy that stuff to JSFiddle to give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float the label left and text align the buttons & image.

```css
div {
  text-align: right;
}
button,
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
label {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>I'm a label</label>

  <button>Button 1</button>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-50-50-6.jpg" alt="" />
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want it all in one line with img between buttons?
Here is the solution based on your styling: http://jsfiddle.net/cn61gxmh/6/

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <label>label </label>
    <div class="buttons">
       <button>button 1</button>
       <img></img><button>button 2</button>
    </div>
 </div>

    .wrapper img{
width: 90px;
height: 40px;
margin-top: 5px;}

.buttons{text-align: right;}

button{
   margin-top: 12px;
   height: 45px;
   width: 45px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That does not produce the required output.

Comment: it displays following in 1 line: label , button1, img, button2.
http://screencast.com/t/gOrpE7zR
Tested in Chrome.

Can you provide a link where you are tesing it?

Comment: If you check the question the requirement is for the label on the left side of the screen and the rest on the right side.